# pdflatex removes highlights in the included PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf, highlighting

I have a figure in the PDF format and there are some texts in the figure (pdf) are highlighted. However, when I include this PDF file into latex document, the highlights are automatically removed. Do you know to to preserve the highlights? I am using PdfLaTeX to compile the TeX documents. The minimal working example provide below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure in PDF format can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ztfdhyakq3l084z/W0HozWyXFv).
However, you can use any pdf file that contains highlights to see the problem.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your PDF figure contains PDF annotations, which are only supported by some PDF viewers. Basically, an annotation is not part of the figure, but a distinct object that is put on top of it, can be edited, moved around and so on. To become part of the image, it need to be "flattened", e.g., by printing into another PDF file.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I found the same solution as yours. "Print as PDF" is a working solution. However, an advantaged of this solution is that it almost produces blank space and we need to crop it later on.

Comment: There is no blank space if you open the PDF and print it with Chrome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you highlight and annotate inside a PDF figure  with tools such as Acrobat, Preview, or Evince, these elements do not become part of the PDF figure – they are stored as PDF annotations.

Basically, annotations are distinct objects that are put on top of the PDF figure, can be edited, moved around and so on by viewers that support this. They also may look differently in every viewer, as the PDF specifications only defines the annotation types and properties, but not how they are to be rendered on screen.

To have annotations become part of the figure, the PDF need to be "flattened", for instance, by printing it (including annotations) into another PDF file. However, this is not supported by many PDF viewers.

Comment: Acrobat has 'preflight' that can be used to flatten the pdf. Choose "PDF fixups -> Flatten annotations and form fields" in the profile list and go.

Comment: `for instance, by printing it (including annotations) into another PDF file.` I can't get this to work. I have annotations and when I print the PDF to a PDF file, these are lost. I am not able to see an option so far to tell adobe acrobat pro 9 I am using to "keep" the annotation. Will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I experimented with the other solutions posted here. I sketch a brief summary for future reference in case someone incurs the same issue.

Basically the solution is to annotate the pdf with a custom editor and then print it to pdf. For this I tried two options:

1. print through the pdf editor --> I used `Okular` in ubuntu and it works, however the resulting document is a bit blurred
2. open the annotated pdf with Chrome and print it --> this worked for me with a nice and scalable output*

*However, I have to say that controlling the extent of the highlighted text is a nightmare, at least in the case of text within a table. In my case I highlighted just few words in a cell, but when I printed it the result was all the cell highlighted...I didn't fully understand why, but I suspect it happens when you highlight a space before/after the first/last word of each highlighted group of words.